# How to search belongs_to association attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, arel, rails-activerecord

I have two entities `Posts` and `Comments` associated as follows

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :msg
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :msg
  belongs_to :post
  scope :search, lambda { |msg| where(arel_table[:msg].matches('%#{msg}%'))}
end
```

The `scope :search` now search only for `comments(msg)`, I want to write another scope to search for `posts(msg)` in `comments`.

How to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following (I favor class methods than scopes with lambdas because they look cleaner and are easier to read)

```
# comment.rb

def self.search(msg)
  where(arel_table[:msg].matches('%#{msg}%'))
end

def self.post_search(msg)
  joins(:post).where(Post.arel_table[:msg].matches("%#{msg}%"))
end
```